# Existing framework for checking and validating against a set of rules, then generating a report?

Tags: java, python, .net

I am a technical writer, authoring course material for customer enablement. **Each lab guide** is essentially a **collection of HTML and XML files organized into folders and subfolders**.

I would like to **ensure each lab guide complies with a set of rules** regarding the **structure** (e.g. "every folder and subfolder should contain a file called Overview.htm") or the **file contents** (e.g. "every Overview.htm file should contain a  tag right before the  tag"). Then I would like to **generate a report with checkmarks in front of every rule for every project**. This way, I can run my validator every night (through our Continuous Integration server) and check the consistency of the projects. If something goes wrong, I can spot it immediately.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel if such a framework already exists. Python would be my language of choice, but .NET and Java are also acceptable. I already have a good idea of how to code the rules with each of these languages. I am just looking for a framework that builds on top of these rules and automate the whole process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I thought about using Drools for a moment, but then determined it was an overkill. I only have a few rules to enforce, and the learning curve is too steep. So I turned to the [Specification Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) and found a nice modern C# implementation on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670115/Specification-pattern-in-Csharp). I customized the predicate specification to include an error message and the list of expected values, and came up with a clean and scalable solution to my problem.